# Update field in a table on click in rails using javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am working on my rails app, I have a field in my portfolios table **num_of_click** which is suppose to store the number of times I have clicked on a button. I am able to get the counter which displays the number of times I am clicking the button but I am not able to figure out how to store that value in the database (increment that value on every click.)

Help me figure out that problem.

show.html.erb

```
<button onclick="CountFun()" class="btn btn-success float-right">Copy</button>

<div id="showCount"></div>

<script>
  var cnt=0;
  function CountFun(){
    cnt=parseInt(cnt)+parseInt(1);
    var divData=document.getElementById("showCount");
    divData.innerHTML="Number of Downloads: ("+cnt +")"
  }
</script>
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "portfolios", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "num_of_click"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: did you try sending an ajax request?

Comment: @kcsujeet no I didnt. can you give me a little idea so I can have a look.

Comment: check out documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started    .... using jquery would be simpler: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/